# Sub-domain REST call work in FF not in IE

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser, cross-domain, getjson

I have an HTML page designed with bootstrap that calls a REST Service to update info the DB. Here is the javascript:

```
$.support.cors = true;

$.ajaxSetup ({
  // Disable caching of AJAX responses
  cache: false,
  async: false
});

$("#submitemail").click(function() {

$.getJSON('http://sub.mydomain.com/getinfo/'+ 
                 encodeURIComponent($('#emailaddress').val()), 
                 function(resp) {
                    //do something here
                  }); 
});
```

Works in FF.

Using IE - If I open the html file from my desktop and run...it will call the sub.mydomain.com and fetch the info. However, if I open the site from www.mydomain.com and the invoke the method - nothing. Checked with Fiddler - IE does not even send a request.

Comment: Does sub.mydomain.com return valid `JSONP` when the callback parameter exists?

Comment: you see if there are an error in the IE console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a subdomain from your main domain like this. It's a 'cross-domain' request, and the request will break. It should never work from `www.mydomain.com` -- even on FF.
I don't know how it does.

Anyway, how is your server built? Is the `sub.mydomain.com` folder within mydomain.com/?Such as:

Top level domain:

`http_public/mydomain.com/`

Sub Domains

`http_public/mydomain.com/sub_domains/sub.mydomain.com/`

?

If the file structure is like this, then you can allow access directory and use

`url: '/sub_domains/sub.mydomain.com/getinfo'+whatever`

Else, you need to use `JSONP`

[JSONP or "JSON with padding" is a complement to the base JSON data format. It provides a method to request data from a server in a different domain, something prohibited by typical web browsers because of the Same origin policy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: I have nginx running in the front and NodeJS+Restify for the API. Nginx serves static HTML from a folder for the main www.mydomain site. REST calls are serviced by api.mydomain. Nginx routes the api to NodeJs. On FF it works fine..but on IE nothing is sent by the browser.

Comment: Also, I am using JSONP calls...$.getJSON(). And have the $.support.cors = true;